# How can I show that $(m\cdot1)(n\cdot1) =(n m) \cdot 1$ in the integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the integral domain $D$,
how can I show that $(m\cdot1)(n\cdot1) =(nm) \cdot 1$?

($m$, $n$ are positive integers)

($m\cdot 1$ means $1+1+ \ldots +1$ for $m$ summands)

(I think this seems obvious if it is just product of integers but it isn't so I'm confused)

Comment: Well, how have you defined $m$ and $n$?

Comment: I'm sorry! I define m and n as positive integers!

Comment: This follows from distributivity if you get your hands dirty and count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplicative operation of $\mathbb N$ on $D$ is *defined* recursively per (using bold for elements of $D$ for clarity)

$$ 0\cdot {\bf x} = {\bf 0} $$
$$ (n+1)\cdot {\bf x} = n\cdot {\bf x}+{\bf x}  $$
and can be extedned to $\mathbb Z$ via
$$ (-n)\cdot {\bf x} = -(n\cdot {\bf x})$$

Using this we can show more generally (you ask only for ${\bf x}={\bf y}={\bf 1}$) by induction that 
$$ (n\cdot {\bf x})(m\cdot {\bf y})=(nm)\cdot ({\bf xy})$$
If $n=0$ this follows from ${\bf 0z}={\bf 0}$ and the induction step goes like this:
$$\begin{align} ((n+1)\cdot{\bf x})(m\cdot {\bf y})&=(n\cdot{\bf x}+{\bf x})(m\cdot {\bf y})\\&=(n\cdot {\bf x})(m\cdot {\bf y})+{\bf x}(m\cdot {\bf y})\\&=(nm)\cdot ({\bf xy})+m\cdot ({\bf xy})\\&=((n+1)m)\cdot ({\bf xy})\end{align}$$
Well, to be honest, we silently used two intermediate results:
$$ {\bf x}(n\cdot {\bf y}) = n\cdot({\bf xy})$$
$$ n\cdot {\bf x} + m\cdot {\bf x} =  (n+m)\cdot {\bf x} $$
But these have also straightfoward induction proofs.

Answer (score 3):

$$m⋅1=\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{m times}$$

$$n⋅1=\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{n times}$$

$$(m⋅1)(n⋅1)=(\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{m times})(\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{n times})=$$

Use distributive rule:

$$\underbrace{(\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{n times})+(\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{n times})+...+(\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{n times})}_\text{m times}=$$

Use associativity:

$$(\underbrace{ 1+1+…+1}_\text{mn times})=(mn).1$$

The last equality is obtained by definition.

Comment: Even if not mentioned explicitly, this proof requires uses/requires induction. +1

Answer (score 2):

This is an application of the distributive law and can be easily proved by induction.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I've had a hard day - I've deleted "I think" - which was mainly intended as an encouragement to think.